# How can I separate dynamodb table and its GSI in different cloudformation stack?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I am using `cloudformation` to manage AWS infra. And I'd like to separate dynamodb talbe and its GSI in different cloudformation stack. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, you **can't do this**. [GlobalSecondaryIndexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html) are part of [AWS::DynamoDB::Table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html).

CloudFormation **does not provide** a separate resource for deploying `GlobalSecondaryIndexes`. The only way to do this outside of `AWS::DynamoDB::Table` would be through a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) which you would have to develop.